# System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.Int32]' to type [System.Int32]'

Tags: c#

This is the task: A sequence of non-empty strings stringList is given.
Get a sequence of ascending sorted integer values equal to the lengths of the strings included
in the stringList sequence.
This is my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Task2(IEnumerable<string> stringList)
    {

        var result = from item in stringList
                   orderby item.Length descending
                   select item;

        return (IEnumerable<int>)result;
        
    }
```

But when I try to start tests, I have this message: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.String,System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]'.
What's wrong???

Comment: You sort a collection of string and you would return as a collection of int? Change signature of the function to `public static IEnumerable<string> ..` and `return result`

Answer (score 0):

You can use method chaining:

`stringList.Select(item => item.Length).OrderBy(item => item).AsEnumerable()`

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `item` which is a string, but your return type is a list of numbers. To make it work change the return type to `IEnumerable<string>`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Task2(IEnumerable<string> stringList)
{
    var result = from item in stringList
                 orderby item.Length descending
                 select item;

    return (IEnumerable<string>)result;
}
```

Or if you need the length of the strings then change the select to return with the length

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Task2(IEnumerable<string> stringList)
{
    var result = from item in stringList
                 orderby item.Length descending
                 select item.Length;

    return (IEnumerable<int>)result;
}
```